# Ajax, jQuery- Update Database when Checkboxes is/are checked or unchecked

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, checkbox

I have a system that lets the admin set the discount Enabled or Disabled for specific discount type, discount values are already set in the database :

```
<li>Discount For Items</li>
<li><input type="checkbox" class="discount" value="1"></li>

<li>Discount For General Ordesr</li>
<li><input type="checkbox" class="discount" value="2"></li>

<li>Discount For Preferred Customer</li>
<li><input type="checkbox" class="discount" value="2"></li>
```

I want to update the row  `enable` (boolean) using jQuery/Ajax, if it's `checked` then do selected `discount type`, if `unchecked` disable `discount type`.
I really need your help and hope my explanation is understandable.

Comment: First of all you can't use the same id for multiple elements!

Comment: that's why i also put a class `:)`

Comment: no you don't get it, one id per one item. IDs can't be reused in the same page.

Comment: What do you need help with? We won't be creating your PHP file for you!

Comment: I only need jQuery/Ajax hints on handling checkboxes! come on :)

Answer (score 1):

you can try something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('input.discount').change(function(){

    $this = $(this);

    $.post(
      "my-php-file.php",
      {
        value: $this.val(),
        checked: $this.is(':checked')
      },
      function(data){
        // do something with returned data
      },
      'json'
    );
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

With jQuery you could do something like this, but you need your server-side logic(service) to do actual database manipulation (we are passing **discount-type** as a **type** along with AJAX POST request).

```
    <li>Discount For Items</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" class="discount" data-discount-type="all" /></li>

    <li>Discount For General Ordesr</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" class="discount" data-discount-type="general" /></li>

    <li>Discount For Preferred Customer</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" class="discount" data-discount-type="customer" /></li>

    // JavaScript
    $(function(){
       var url = 'my-php-file.php';

       $('input:checkbox').on('click', function(){
           var $this = $(this);
       if($this.prop('checked'))
          $.post(url,{type : $this.data('discount-type') }).done(function(response){
             // success custom logic
          });
      });
    });
```